# The element inside of the SwiftUIPager is hidden when the screen border is touched

Tags: swift, swiftui

In my code I have HStack with Buttons inside of Pager. Button's label is Text view with RoundedRectangle as it's overlay.

```swift
Pager(page: vm.selectedWeekPage, data: vm.deltaWeeksArray, id: \.self) { deltaWeek in
    HStack{
        ForEach (vm.fetchWeek(vm.deltaWeek(delta: deltaWeek)), id: \.self){
            day in
            Button {
                vm.selectedDay = day
            } label: {
                    Text("\(vm.extractDate(date: day, format: "dd"))")
                        .font(.custom("Unbounded", size: 20))
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .foregroundColor(Color(tm.getTheme().foregroundColor))
                        .frame(width: 42, height: 42)
                        .overlay(content: {
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15, style: .continuous)
                                .stroke(lineWidth: 2)
                                .foregroundColor(Color(tm.getTheme().foregroundColor))
                                .frame(width: 46, height: 46)
                                .fixedSize()
                        })
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            }
        }
    }
    .padding(.horizontal, 18)
}
.singlePagination()
.pagingPriority(.simultaneous)
.onPageChanged({ page in
    if page >= vm.deltaWeeksArray.count - 2 {
        (1..<4).forEach { _ in
            vm.deltaWeeksArray.append((vm.deltaWeeksArray.last ?? 0) + 1)
            vm.deltaWeeksArray.removeFirst()
            vm.selectedWeekPage.index -= 1
        }
    } else if page <= 1 {
        (1..<4).forEach { _ in
            vm.deltaWeeksArray.insert((vm.deltaWeeksArray.last ?? 0) + 1, at: 0)
            vm.deltaWeeksArray.removeLast()
            vm.selectedWeekPage.index += 1
        }
    }
})
.itemSpacing(50)
.frame(maxHeight: 48)
.padding(.horizontal, -18)
```

Bug happens when I transition to different page. `.stroke()` hides when Button touches the edge of screen.

Recording of bug:

[Link](https://youtu.be/6sU35ARQH9o)

Actually I don't really know what to do... I tried using ZStack instead of `.overlay()`,extracting text from the label on the button. That didn't work

Comment: What is _Pager_?

Comment: It is SwiftUIPager object. https://github.com/fermoya/SwiftUIPager?ysclid=lecmf467c2366185370

Comment: Unlikely anyone will find you an answer here if it's a bug in the repo. I see you've raised an issue on github, which is probably the best way to handle it.

Comment: I thought maybe I did something wrong. I worked with this repo couple times and I have never met such behavior